# Error of using urllib.request library in python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

i try to read url for using urllib.request library in python.
but there are so many error in shell.
i wrote code following this.

```
import urllib.request
req=urllib.request
req.urlopen("http://www.naver.com")
```

but there are some error following this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    req.urlopen("http://news.naver.com/")
  File "C:\Users\kyu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 162, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\kyu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 465, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\kyu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 483, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Users\kyu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 443, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\kyu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1268, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Users\kyu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1243, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\kyu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 1174, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\kyu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 282, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\kyu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 251, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response
```

what's wrong??
i don't know why this happening
i use python 3.5.1 and windows8.1 64bit.

Comment: Read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.RemoteDisconnected) for this. It says that the _remote end has closed the connection_. Try another site like [httpbin](http://httpbin.org/) and see if you still get the same error.

Comment: I guess, you should try setting some user-agents.

Comment: i already try req.urlopen("http://httpbin.org/"). but there are same error. i don't know that what is  "some user-agents"??

Comment: even i use someone's code. import requests
MAX_RETRIES = 20
url ='https://httpbin.org/'

session = requests.Session()
adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=MAX_RETRIES)
session.mount('https://', adapter)
session.mount('http://', adapter)

r = session.get(url)
print(r.content). 

but...i can see same error